# Typo3 8.7.8: indexed_search ignores TYPO3SEARCH_begin

Tags: typo3, tx-indexed-search

I am using indexed_search and I have the problem that the WHOLE SITE is crawled - including the navigation. So if I search for a word which is part of the main navigation all sites are displayed in the result.

I have added `<--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->` and `<--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->` in my template - and these markers are included in the HTML output correctly. The markers do not surround the navigation, of course.

I am using:

```
Typo3: 8.7.8
tx_indexed_search 8.7.9
site_crawler 6.1.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out what cost me several hours... It's unbelievable what happened to me. I copied the `<--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->` pattern from a tutorial. 
Today I looked at the code again - and now I noticed, that the pattern was not colored in green in my IDE - like all the other HTML comments. Hmmm...

Finally I found out that these are not the same:

```
<–-TYPO3SEARCH_begin-–>
<--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->
```

The first line has a dash (minus) symbol which is not the standard character, but some odd UTF-8 sign. (Hex 93).

Don't know where I copied the pattern from, but that guy must have a strange kind of humor

Comment: that probably was no special humor of someone. I would claim some wordprocessing responsible. Especially Word does some of these 'tricks' to produce clean texts (having correct semantics) and especially if you can access utf8 you have multiple special characters you could/would not enter with the default keyboard. and the characters seem to be `mdash` which represent a dash with the length of  the letter `m`. (there also is an `ndash` smaller but also bigger than a normal dash, which represents a minus)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding <--TYPO3SEARCH_end--> and the very beginning of the document. Thus everything is ignored until the begin marker.